# how to move to the perticular image of the horizantalscrollview in android

Tags: android, gallery, horizontalscrollview

if we click on the third image of the gallery then that image will be displayed and if we scroll right then next image will be displayed and if we scroll left then previous image will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider rephrasing your question, it is unclear what you are looking for.
I will hazard a guess that you want to implement a gallery, using the Gallery class and displaying the selected image in a larger view below.

What you need to do then is to follow the tutorial on:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html
but instead of having the Gallery as the root element of the layout xml, use a LinearLayout or other, where you put both the Gallery and an ImageView.
Then implement an onItemSelectedListener for the Gallery, in which you bind the ImageView to the selected image resource.

Comment: for( i=0;i<hash1.size();i++)
       {        
       
        //String file=imgList1.get(i).toString();        
      //System.out.println("file is:"+file);      
      ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
      imgView.setId(i);
      imgView.setPadding(50, 50, 50,50);
      imgView.setImageResource(hash1.get(i));
      
      linearLayout.addView(imgView);  }

Comment: this linear layout will be added to the horizontalscrollview

Comment: then how to display the perticular image visible

Comment: @ram: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are looking for. If my answer doesn't help you, hopefully someone elses will. If you haven't already, follow the tutorial I linked, I think that it will give you a better idea of your options.

Comment: @ram: set an OnItemSelectedListener on the gallery, and there bind the ImageView to the resource id of the image in the Gallery